# If a sufficient statistic is constant, then the distributions are all the same

Tags: probability, statistics

Let a family of distributions having pdf of the form $f(x;\theta)=h(x)e^{\eta(\theta)T(x)+B(\theta)}.$
Suppose for some $\theta_0$ and some constant $c$ such that
$$P_{\theta_0}(T=c)=1$$
then $$P_{\theta}(T=c)=1$$ for all $\theta$ and all the distributions in the family are the same.

I got stuck on how to prove this one.

Comment: Are you using $T$ in two different different ways or do you mean $P_{\theta}(T(X)=c)=1$?

Comment: I mean $P_{\theta}(T(X)=c)=1$.